# Open Facebook Page from Prefrence Screen

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to implement a Facebook page link on my settings screen. I have tried some code but its not working. How do I open a Facebook page in the Facebook application or in a Web browser?

```html
facebook.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener()
{
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {
        public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context)
        {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            try
            {
                int versionCode =
                    packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
                if (versionCode >= 3002850) //newer versions of fb app
              return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + FACEBOOK_URL;
                else //older versions of fb app
              return "fb://page/" + FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return FACEBOOK_URL; //normal web url
            }
  }
      
        Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(this);
        facebookIntent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookUrl));
        startActivity(facebookIntent);
    }
});
```

I am having three errors:

1.

```
public String getFacebookPageURL(Context context) {
```

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token ")", ;       expected
>     - Syntax error on token "(", ;       expected

2.

```
String facebookUrl = getFacebookPageURL(this);
```

> The method getFacebookPageURL(Context) in the type new
>   Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){} is not   applicable for the
>   arguments (new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){})

3.

```
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

> Return type for the method is missing

How to solve this?

Comment: Show us you code and explain your problem(s) please and we'll help fixing it.

Comment: Do you want to login with facebook in your android application?@Rajubhai Rathod

Comment: no...I just want open facebook page from my settings screen

Comment: hi @Quality Catalyst I have added code which I am trying. Thanks